# CURL/GuzzleHttp and PUT(ting) a json payload in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to PUT a json payload for jet.com but I am getting NULL as a response each time and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I created a json payload that looks like this:

```
{
  "alt_order_id": "12345",
  "shipments": [
    {
      "alt_shipment_id": "11223344",
      "shipment_tracking_number": "1Z12342452342",
      "response_shipment_date": "2014-06-11T18:00:00.0000000-04:00",
      "response_shipment_method": "ups_ground",
      "expected_delivery_date": "2014-06-11T18:00:00.0000000-04:00",
      "ship_from_zip_code": "12061",
      "carrier_pick_up_date": "2014-06-11T18:00:00.0000000-04:00",
      "carrier": "UPS",
      "shipment_items": [
        {
          "alt_shipment_item_id": "129900120",
          "merchant_sku": "15a1010",
          "response_shipment_sku_quantity": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I first tried GuzzleHttp but could not figure out what to use as the key for the payload and kept getting an error so I opt'd to try cURL.

I created this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://merchant-api.jet.com/api/orders/'.$order_id.'/shipped');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        dd($ch);
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
```

But I keep getting back null as the response and the item is not updating on their end. When I die and dump I am getting this:

```
curl resource @290 ▼
  url: "https://merchant-api.jet.com/api/orders/000000000/shipped"
  content_type: null
  http_code: 0
  header_size: 0
  request_size: 0
  filetime: 0
  ssl_verify_result: 0
  redirect_count: 0
  total_time: 0.0
  namelookup_time: 0.0
  connect_time: 0.0
  pretransfer_time: 0.0
  size_upload: 0.0
  size_download: 0.0
  speed_download: 0.0
  speed_upload: 0.0
  download_content_length: -1.0
  upload_content_length: -1.0
  starttransfer_time: 0.0
  redirect_time: 0.0
  redirect_url: ""
  primary_ip: ""
  certinfo: []
  primary_port: 0
  local_ip: ""
  local_port: 0
}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I know my OAuth key is working since I am able to GET data passing it in the header. Thanks and let me know if there is anything glaring. I am pretty novice with cURL.

Comment: As I see you are using: `CURLAUTH_ANY is an alias for CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_DIGEST | CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM` Do you need to auth?  If yes, where is the credentials?

Comment: I did have an addition  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: bearer (and the token) ']) but it didn;t seem to work and I am not sure if was in a new CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER or as an array in the one there. Thanks!

Comment: Next time please post the actual code (and use asterix for credentials), because others could thought you just forget to auth.

Comment: Check your `$order_id`. before send the curl. Are you sure is there an order number at jet.com?

Comment: Sorry about the missing code. I am sure the order id is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using guzzle, json data is passed in as part of the $options array you pass the guzzle request method.

An example:

```
<?php

$options = array(
    'json' => array(
        'data' => 'value',
        'more' => 'data'
    ),
);

$guzzle->request("POST", "http://some.api/putJson", $options);
```

All data stored under a 'json' key in the options array will be passed in the request.

Hope this helps

---

EDIT: PUT Requests

PUT requests should not use the '**json**' options key to send it's data, it should instead use the '**body**' key.

An example PUT request:

```
<?php

$options = array(
    'body' => array(
        'data' => 'value',
        'more' => 'data'
    ),
);

$guzzle->request("PUT", "http://some.api/putJson", $options);
```

Comment: For guzzle, I see things like query or json as the key. There does not appear to be any key for the PUT to Jet.com. Does the key matter?

Comment: I tried this:  $r = $this->client->put($this->api_prefix.'/orders/'.$order_id.'/shipped',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'bearer '.$this->token,
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
                ],
                'data' => $payload
            ]);
        $result =  json_decode($r->getBody());


and got this Client error: `PUT https://merchant-api.jet.com/api/orders/384232/shipped` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
"errors": [
"Root json has to be a Record"
]
}

Comment: what version of guzzle is being used? PUT is a HTTP method, you would just change POST in my example above to PUT.

Comment: I am using guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2. I did change the POST to PUT but it gave me that error of Root json has to be a Record.

Comment: Have you tried using body as the key? See my update. Thanks